# NextJS: Footer not render on vercel deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

so I want to make a template for the navbar and footer and decide to use a layout like on [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts)

it's working fine on the localhost but when deploy on the vercel for some reason not rendered but just a footer that is not rendered

**Preview**

- on local host
  [image]
- on vercel
  [image]

**Script**

Layoout.js

```js
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

_app.js

```js
import Layout from "../component/Layout";

import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

index.js

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import Featured from "../component/Featured";
import ProductList from "../component/ProductList";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>MarssId</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Featured />
      <ProductList />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Footer.jsx

```js
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Instagram } from "@material-ui/icons";

const Container = styled.div`
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap");
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #93221e;
  display: flex;
`;

const Item = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;

  &:last-child {
    flex: 3;
    padding: 50px;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
`;

const Card = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
`;
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
`;

const Text = styled.p`
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
`;

const Motto = styled.h2`
  color: whitesmoke;
`;

const SocialContainer = styled.div`
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
`;

const SocialIcon = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
`;

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Item>
        <Image src={"/img/1.JPG"} layout={"fill"} objectFit="cover" />
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Card>
          <Motto>MARRS, CANDUNYA CEMILAN!</Motto>
          <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          </Text>
        </Card>
        <Card>
          <Title>Contact</Title>
          <Text>Shopee</Text>
          <SocialContainer>
            <SocialIcon>
              <Instagram />
            </SocialIcon>
          </SocialContainer>
        </Card>
      </Item>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

**What I've tried**

I tried to move the Footer from Layout.js to index.js to make sure the footer work and yes it's working but still in the layout.js the footer is not rendered.

Layoout.js

```js
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

index.js

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import Featured from "../component/Featured";
import ProductList from "../component/ProductList";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>MarssId</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Featured />
      <ProductList />
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

am I missing something here? I don't have any idea what is wrong here

Comment: The footer is there, it's just not styled properly, right?

Comment: @juliomalves not sure for not styled properly because it's working on the localhost but not on the vercel

Comment: What I'm saying is, in the images you shared the contents of the footer are there in the Vercel picture, but the CSS just isn't being applied.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but why is that? is it because im using styled-components?